# Is a 41GB partition enough to install Windows 7 x64 bit in Virtual Box?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, memory, 64-bit, macbook-pro

My MacBook Pro is 4GB of memory and 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5 of Processor. I gave it 41GB for Windows partition. Will this be enough or will it slow down the system to install Windows 7 x64 bit? I'm going to use Windows for my development project with Access and SQL Server. Thanks for input!

Comment: While it is enough for windows, I'm a little worried about the SQL Server/Access space requirements. I suppose you don't have any Windows Server License (which take less disk space that user versions of windows)

Comment: @Kwaio no, I don't do Windows Server and I'm sure my Database will get bigger at times. So I'll switch it to x32 bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your system will run slowly and your VM will run slowly.  4GB RAM is only barely enough to run Win 7 in virtualbox.  You should add more RAM if you can.
- 41GB is just about barely sufficient for Windows 7, Office and SQL Server, but you will probably need to do some optimisation such as turning off hibernation etc, and you will almost certainly run into problems as soon as you start applying updates.  After a year or two Windows 7 alone will need more than 41GB - on my laptop I got a few months ago, C:\Windows is 32GB now.
- if you need more than minimal performance my recommendation would be to get more disk space and dual boot instead of running a VM

TL;DR you can make this work but not without some problems.

Comment: I disagree, we've got root servers (32-128 GB RAM) in a productive environment and they also run Windows 7 instances where some have 4 GB of RAM only. They've been installed about 2 years now and each of these VM's have 40GB HDD space allocated, that's sufficient. Would avoid installing a x64 OS on a VM, though.

Comment: Your environment sounds different to this question. In this question the host machine has 4GB total. That's to run OSX, virtualbox, Windows 7, Microsoft Office and SQL Server.  It will be constantly thrashing.

Comment: @Colin Pickard I did have the dual boot, the boot camp and just trying new things as I like the use of OSX and wanted to be able to navigate through both easily. I did install it last night and yes, it seems to be a little slow, so I will go ahead and re-install with x32 bit just to be on the safe side. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

you should install a 32Bit Windows 7 because the 64Bit only makes sense when you would assign at least 4GB to the VM. Because you don't have so much RAM, the 32Bit version is better for you.

Comment: But what if he wants to use a 64 bit program?

Comment: 64Bit Access? I doubt this. If he uses so large files he would use a device with much more RAM.

Comment: windows 64 bit can run with less than 4GB of RAM without problem. 64 bit OS has many other advantages, not only large RAM addressable

Comment: I agree that a 32-bit version for a VM should be more than sufficient if he's only going to assign 4 GB of RAM anyway. For instance if an application is storing a single number such as 278 in int32, it'd need 4 byte of memory on a 32-bit system and waste 23 bits (since only 9 bits would be used to represent the number). On a 64-bit machine this would waste 55 bits for the same task. Probably one of the reasons why I run out of RAM even after doubling my RAM since I'm on x64.

Comment: After doing research I'm going to switch back to x32 bit, since my CPU and RAM aren't capable enough to support x64. Thanks for your input all! BTW I'm a SHE gender :)

Comment: sorry about the gender, without a name we don't know this ;)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Not a problem at all :)